# Node.js net.Socket().connect() hangs and doesn't connect to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have a server and a client set up using the `net` module for Node.js.

Here is my server's code:

```js
const server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.on("data", function(data) {
        // Do stuff with the connection
        socket.end();
    });
});
server.listen(this.port);
```

Here is my client's code:

```js
const client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(this.port, this.host, function() {
    client.write("Test Message");
});
```

When run on the same machine, both of these work fine, but when I try to connect from a different computer, the client hangs at `client.connect()` forever (until I terminate the process). When I tried to use the `telnet` command in command prompt, I don't get a response from the server, but the client doesn't just say connection refused. What's going on here?

Comment: check the port is available and open on the server

Comment: @CodyＧ How do I check if it's available?

Comment: it's a combination of using things like `ping` to check the client can reach the server (but this won't work if it is blocked!), and stuff like `netcat` and `tcpdump` to see if the server actually sees stuff on a specific port/protocol, as well as having an understanding of the client and server (and intermediate) firewalls